# Concept of fitting cubic splines

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, splines

i am reading the elements of statistical learning, and the following diagram is included on page 262. i interpret the text (potentially incorrectly) that the fitted line $\mu(x)$ is a linear combination / mixture of 7 basis functions, with the mixture weigts determined by $\beta$. However - this does not link in the concept of the knots, or give me an intuition on how to select the basis functions h(x). Can someone give me some hints on how and where this is different from fitting a mixture model of 7 individual functions? [image]

Comment: Take a look at here http://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/9184